# Issue with inserting a node in a linkedlist based on order

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, nodes

So I made a program which creates nodes with int data and adds nodes based on that data from largest to smallest(its a scoreboard). I got it to work but every time it tries to add a node thats bigger than a node already in the list. it places it in the wrong place. I know why its doing that, its because there is no way of going back in a single linked list. im not sure what I can do do place it in the right place.

Output:

Zeus - 50

Ares - 48

Hades - 47

Apollo - 43

Hermes - 45 - not in the right place

Cronus - 38

Hades - 16

Here is my insert node method

```
public void insert(String name, int score) 
    {
        Node node = new Node(name, score);
        if(list == null) 
        {
            list=node;
        }
        else if(list.score <= node.score) 
        {
            node.next = list;
            list = node;
        }

        else 
        {
            Node current = list;
            while(current.score > node.score && current.next != null) 
            {
                current = current.next;
            }
            node.next = current.next;
            current.next = node;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Oleg, is that the only think I would need to change if I switch from `>` to `<=`. If i do that only than the while statement wouldnt move the node postion to a place where I can insert the node.

Comment: It would have to be `node.score <= current.score`, but that's just the same as `current.score > node.score`. Either way, the problem is that the the new node needs to go _before_ `current`, not after.  That means you need to keep track of the node which pointed to `current`, so you can link the new one in with `node.next = previous.next; previous.next = node;`; note that `previous.next == current`.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson Thank You so much.